# How to play two separate audio and video tracks in a single player without creating any output file in android?

Tags: android, audio, video, android-mediaplayer, composition

I have one audio file and one video file, I just want to have a composition of both audio and video and play it in a single player without creating any output file.

I have done the same thing in iOS using AVMutableComposition, AVMutableCompositionTrack and played it using AVPlayer.

Can anyone help me to achieve the same in android.

Comment: Have u got any solution?

Comment: I want to do this too.. Please everybody, if you found something solution -- post there)